# Group subsequent object entries having same property value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the issue and I try to solve it a couple of days and I don't have an idea how to bit that.

I have Object with Objects inside that and it looks like that:

```
const messages = {
    key1:{
         author:"author1",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
    }
    key2:{
         author:"author1",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
    }
    key3:{
         author:"author2",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
    }
    key4:{
         author:"author1",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
    }
    key5:{
         author:"author2",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
    }
}
```

and I want to group that by author and when Object[0].author equal Object[1].author put to this same array/object but if Object[0].author not equal Object[1].author they are putted to different array/object.

I want to create a sort that something looks like code bellow.

```
const soortedMessages = {
    {
     key1:{
         author:"author1",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
     }
     key2:{
         author:"author1",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
     }
    },

    {
         key3:{
         author:"author2",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
     }
    },
     {
         key4:{
         author:"author1",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
     }
    },
     {
         key5:{
         author:"author2",
         time:"time",
         value:"some text",
     },

}
```

My question is.
There is some way to sort it like this?

Comment: I like the task. What have you tried already?

Comment: I think you meant `soortedMessages` to be an array

Comment: Honestly, I tried sorted that with _.groupBy and do something with that. I tried Object.keys with map and try put to Array. Then looked documentation in lodash to find something that helps me bite that, and another 100 StackOverflow topics.

@GrégoryNEUT it can be array.

Comment: This should look like array with 1st author1 messages as to author2 then create a new array with author2 messages when author1 write something then create another array with author1 messages etc. just like you have on messenger if you write to somebody your messages are in 1 array if somebody writes to you is another array but if you answer on it create new 3rd array and when he answer to you with couple messages that going to another 4th array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected output is not a valid object, assuming it has to be an array, you may regroup those entries, using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const src = {key1:{author:"author1",time:"time",value:"some text",},key2:{author:"author1",time:"time",value:"some text",},key3:{author:"author2",time:"time",value:"some text",},key4:{author:"author1",time:"time",value:"some text",},key5:{author:"author2",time:"time",value:"some text",}},

      {result} = Object
        .entries(src)
        .reduce((r,[key,o]) => {
          !r.currentAuthor || r.currentAuthor != o.author ?
          (r.currentAuthor = o.author, r.result.push({[key]:o})) :
          Object.assign(r.result[r.result.length-1], {[key]:o})
          return r
        }, {currentAuthor:null, result: []})
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Looks great. Thank You very much. I tried to solve it a couple days. Thanks for help :)

Comment: I tried before but was under 15 views or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess following lines will do the trick for you:

```
const result = _.chain(soortedMessages)
   .toPairs()
   .groupBy(([key, val]) => val.author)
   .mapValues(_.fromPairs)
   .value();
```

Comment: that code creates 2 Objects but should be 4. But thank you for your time.